Touchpad 2 finger scroll is way too fast
I have a lenovo t14 gen5 AMD with ubuntu 24.04 and Gnome 46. As it's a recent laptop, I have a lot of painful problems with it. The most annoying right now is the touchpad 2 finger scroll that is way too fast. I was able to configure sensibility in firefox that makes it bearable, but most applications are unusable.
I tried to install synaptics driver "xserver-xorg-input-synaptics" but after a restart nothing changed. I tried to install other utilitaries like imwheel without more success.
I cannot find touchpad in xinput list:
~$ xinput
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:15                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:15              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:15              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:15                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]

I found another post saying the kernel is not compatible with my touchpad.
Is there any solution to configure the global touchpad sensitivity ? Maybe it'll be simpler on another linux distro ?
Do you know of a community of Thinkpad users with whom I could share my problems? Does the lenovo support could help me in that case as they support ubuntu.

Are you running x or Wayland? Ubuntu defaults to Wayland. I have the t14 and two finger scroll is perfect.

Yes I installed default ubuntu with Walyand. You have the t14 gen 5 AMD ?

Yes, that's the model I have.
